# Mysql: Multiple Self Join?

Tags: php, mysql, self-join

I'm building a symptom checker. As the user picks symptoms, we suggest other symptoms from ailments that have the user selected symptoms in common until we can narrow down to a specific ailment. I have this table.

```
ailment_symptoms 
+----+----------+-----------+
|id  |ailment_id|symptom_id |
+----+----------+-----------+
|1   | 1        |  1        |
|2   | 1        |  2        |
|3   | 2        |  1        |
|4   | 2        |  3        |
|5   | 3        |  3        |
|6   | 3        |  2        |
|7   | 4        |  1        |
|8   | 4        |  2        |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

If I want to select ailment_ids of entries that have symptom_id 1 and 2, I use this self join query.

```
SELECT t1.ailment_id
FROM ailment_symptoms t1
JOIN ailment_symptoms t2 ON t1.ailment_id = t2.ailment_id
WHERE t1.symptom_id =  '1'
AND t2.symptom_id =  '2'
```

which will return

```
+----------+
|ailment_id|
+----------+
| 1        |
| 4        |
+----------+
```

How do I do it when there are more than two symptom_ids. I want to write a php code that will build for as many symptoms as the users enters. code should look like:

```
$user_symptoms = array($symptom_id_1, $symptom_id_2, $symptom_id_3);  //as many symptom as the user picks
$query = "SELECT t1.ailment_id FROM ailment_symptoms t1";

foreach($user_symptoms AS $symptoms){
      //here is where we construct the multiple self join and append it to $query
      //please replace this comment with appropriate code
 }

 $query .= "WHERE ";
 //loop through $user_symptoms and append t1.symptom_id =  '$user_symptom[0]' AND '....'
```

Please help me replace the comments with the appropriate code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also do this with aggregation.  It might be easier for you to construct the queries like this, because it is easier to handle the additional attributes.

```
SELECT s.ailment_id
FROM ailment_symptoms s
WHERE s.symptom_id in (1, 2)
GROUP BY s.ailment_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.symptom_id) = 2;
```

You just have to be sure that the "2" matches the number of elements in the list in the `where` clause.  Then it will generalize to any number of symptoms.

Comment: so if i have symptom_ids 2, 4, 6, 9.. the query will be

        SELECT s.ailment_id
       FROM ailment_symptoms s
       WHERE s.symptom_id in (2, 4, 6, 9)
       GROUP BY s.ailment_id
       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.symptom_id) = 4;


yeah?

Comment: Assuming there I include a third column `intensity` with values `acute    normal     mild` . How can i add a filter that includes ailment_id that has a symptom in the user_selected group and intensity of `acute`...something like
 
`...WHERE (s1.symptom_id = '1' AND s1.intensity='acute')`

Comment: You can change the `where` clause to be what you need.  The `having` will still count the number of distinct symptoms so that should be ok.

Comment: Can you please give me an example. symptoms are not the same for all the symptoms. Eg some can have mild headache with acute stomach pain ....and so on...